# Find min max with other attribute?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Let's say I have the table with
`time_created, view_type, view_id` columns in clickhouse.

How to find min and max `time_created`  with appropriate `view_id` grouped by `view_type`?

This is starting sql:

```
select min(time_created) as min_time_created,
max(time_created) as max_time_created,
view_type  from views 
group by view_type;
```

And how to add `view_id` to each result column. Also considering `time_created` is not unique.

Comment: "Also considering time_created is not unique" - does it mean that one min/max *time_created* may be related more than one *view_id*? Could you describe the corner cases on an example of input data and required result?

Comment: @vladimir, Yes, there could be many views at a time. Guess don't need the corner cases, since your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this query should help:

```sql
SELECT view_type, 
  min(time_created) as min_time_created,
  max(time_created) as max_time_created
  argMin(view_id, time_created) as min_view_id, 
  argMax(view_id, time_created) as max_view_id
FROM views
GROUP BY view_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and use window function

```
Select 
      MIN(time_created) OVER (PARTITION BY view_type) AS Min_time_created,
      MAX(time_created) OVER (PARTITION BY view_type) AS Min_time_created,
      View_type  
from Views ;
```